# Why isn't my dlink N300 DIR-615 use 5Ghz band?

Tags: macbook, 802.11n

I have a dlink N300 DIR-615 dual band N router which i have put it in 802.11n mode via router settings but when i attempt to connect it using my mac which supports  AC wifi but it only uses 2.4Ghz even when I am near the router!

Questions:

Why doesn't my Mac connect using 5Ghz to my  dual band router?

I have heard that a dual band router broadcasts 2 different networks for 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz seperately. Is it true?

PS. My router does not broadcast two different networks at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Which part of the DIR-615 is a dual-band router?

Comment: According to DLINK page - https://www.dlink.com/mk/mk/products/dir-615-wireless-n-300-router - this router does not support 5GHz? Are you sure you got the correct model number?

Comment: @Darius I am wrong. I don't have a dual band router. The box says only N600 supports dual band.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DIR-615 is a not a dual-band router and does not operate on the 5GHz band.